# Winforms Control Stealing WndProc WM_NCHITEST

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I am building a form in C# that uses the `WM_NCHITEST` event in the `WndProc` function. It works perfectly with no controls on the page, but when I added a panel to the page my `WndProc` function stopped receiving `WM_NCHITEST` events. Any idea what I can do to stop this?

**UPDATE**: My window in normally borderless, but when I do run it in bordered mode the `WM_NCHITTEST` event is called when the cursor mouses over the window frame, leaving me to think that the form size control I have (Chromium Embedded Web Browser) is intercepting the messages. Any way to wrest WndProc control back from a unrully window?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0083) //WM_NCAlSIZE
    {
        if (borderless)
        {
            return; //Works even with a control on the page.
        }
    }
    if (m.Msg == 0x0084) //WM_NCHITEST
    {
        Debug.Print("If there is a control on the page I won't print :(");
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that your panel is completely overlapping the form.  So it is the panel that gets all the hit-test messages.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 complications running Chromium Embedded Web Browser firstly it creates its own window and attaches as a child to yours which means you need to intercept the WndProc of the child window. Secondly CefSharp runs with `multi_threaded_message_loop=true` which actually fires up a new thread to process messages for the browser which means you need to be a little careful going back and forth from your UI thread and its one.

The solution involves liberal use of PInvoke so I have made a gist for it.

[Method to watch a child window messages specifically for use with CefSharp Chromium Embedded Web Browser](https://gist.github.com/iwantedue/7887305)

Comment: Hi! A very interesting answer! I'm using a different version that you are (CEF 3.2454.1344.g2782fb8, Chromium 45.0.2454.101 and .net 4.5.1.) so my child windows have different names: `CefBrowserWindow`, `Chrome_WidgetWin_0`, `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND`. Which one should I use?